# (JAVA) Why do I need to put com.company at the start of my program and how does this code work?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So basically, I am a beginner to Java, and I am taking a course. Firstly, I don't understand why I need com.company at the beginning of this program (using IntelliJ IDEA and JDK 9.0.1). Secondly, I don't understand how this program calls the "calculateTax" method because the only method call is when the double variable "total" is being initialized. Here's the code:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static double subtotal;

    // main function of the program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subtotal = 15.00;
        System.out.println("Subtotal: " + subtotal);
        double total = subtotal + calculateTax(0.08, subtotal);
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    }

    public static double calculateTax(double taxRate, double amountToTax) {
        double tax = amountToTax * taxRate;
        System.out.println("Tax: " + tax);
        return tax;
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

> Subtotal: 15.0
>   Tax: 1.2
>   Total: 16.2
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. *Why do I need to do something and why does this code work?* is clearly too broad and unclear for this site. Please do that reading, specifically [ask] and [mcve],  before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not mandatory to use com.company, you can use your own package name. Package is used to organize classes belonging to the same category or similar functionality. Classes can be downloaded faster as a group rather than one at a time.

To calculate total you will need the result of calculateTax method, so total calculation will be paused and calculateTax method will be called. When calculateTax method is finished and result is returned then total calculation will be resumed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you explained the answer very well and very clearly. I understand now :)